# How can I unlock my Samsung S5 after too many wrong finger prints?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5, locked-out

I have a Samsung S5 with a finger print lock.

After so many attempts (5) it locked and asked for an alternate password which, unfortunately, I did not set up.

Now I cant unlock my phone. I called my server and they advised me to go on here.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Until answers pop up, I recommend starting with out [locked-out tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info), which holds some first aid for situations like this (though I'm not aware we've encountered that fingerprint-special yet). Good luck!

Comment: Can you not sign in with google?

Answer (score 1):

I understand how difficult is this situation. I would suggest few options , either you can go for factory reset try this :

- shut down your device.
- press volume UP+home+ power buttons all together.

This will take you to options where you could find factory reset option. Press volume button to scroll and power to confirm. Unfortunately it will erase up everything.

Or log-in your phone from google account. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue causing major concern I logged into my samsung account, from there down the left side is a list of options one of them is "unlock screen" click that. it opens another window 
with a big button saying "Unlock" click that and with 5 seconds my phone unlocked.

hope this helps.